# display huge data in batches of 100 every hour in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, time, cron, batch-processing

I have a database with more than 600 rows but I can only retrieve/display 100 every hour. So I use

```
select * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
```

to retrieve the first 100. How do I write a script that will retrieve the data in batches of 100 every 1hr so that I can use it in a cron job?

Comment: You will have to store the next offset somewhere.

Comment: Does you need that the record must be selected only once? i.e. previously selected record must not be returned even if it matches "last 100" condition? If so I'd recommend to add a field "shown" into the structure and mark shown records in it. Because the amount of records added since last select may be over 100...

Comment: Use MySQL offsets https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: @Akina exactly. Can you expand on your suggestion?

Comment: @Akina Wouldn't that be space consuming instead of just storing the next offset?

Comment: @vivek_23 I like the idea of storing the next offset somewhere...but how do you do this and also make it automated so that even if the db increases, the script will still work without having to change anything?

Comment: @JaySmoke If you are able to store the offset somewhere, DB row increase won't make any difference since you are fetching only 100 at once. Storing the offset can be in the form of json in a simple file or inside a database(recommended) in a single table.

Comment: @JaySmoke However, I want you to clarify whether any rows would get deleted in the system for some reason? Because that could affect the synchronicity and could also probably skip some rows.

Comment: "I can only retrieve/display 100 every hour"...why? That would be the obvious question. Even 600 is not a big amount.

Comment: @vivek_23 no, the db will be populated continually so it will always increase. The retrieval is just for display purposes. There won't be any deletion after the retrieval.

Comment: Are you in fact wishing to retrieve that most recently added 100 rows every hour? (which is a different question to the one asked)

Comment: @JaySmoke Then the simple offset approach will work. You fetch 100 rows at once, update the offset for the next cron hit. Make a single cron that runs every 2-3 minutes or every hour(however you like) and hits a URL or a script etc.

Comment: @vivek_23 great, I guess now the question is, how to write that script?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution.

1. Add a field for to mark the record was already shown.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD COLUMN shown TINYINT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

NULL will mean that the record was not selected, 1 - that record is marked for selection, 0 - that record was already selected.

2. When you need to select up to 100 records you

2.1. Mark records to be shown

```
UPDATE tablename
SET shown = 1
WHERE shown = 1 
   OR shown IS NULL
ORDER BY shown = 1 DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

`shown = 1` condition in WHERE considered the fact that some records were marked but were not selected due to some error. `shown = 1 DESC` re-marks such records before non-marked.

If there is 100 or less records which were not selected all of them will be marked, else only 100 records with lower id (most ancient) will be marked.

2.2. Select marked records.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE shown = 1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100;
```

2.3. Mark selected records.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET shown = 0
WHERE shown = 1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100;
```

This is applicable when only one client selects the records.

If a lot of clients may work in parallel, and only one cliens must select a record, then use some cliens number (unique over all clients) for to mark a record for selection instead of `1`.

Of course if there is only one client, and you guarantee that selection will not fail, you may simply store last shown ID somewhere (on the client side, or in some service table on the MySQL side) and simply select "next 100" starting from this stored ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id > @stored_id
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100;
```

and

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM tablename
WHERE id > @stored_id
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100;
```

for to store instead of previous `@stored_id`.

Comment: I like the direction, thank you very much, but this doesn't show how this will automate the process every hour till all records are displayed?

Comment: @JaySmoke Create stored procedure which performs all described steps and selects marked records. Call this procedure from the client side by any convenient way.

Comment: Ok, so am thinking, all records are marked 1. I use cronjob to do 2.2 to select 100 every hour and mark them as 2, till it's all done. Once done, the cronjob will return null because all records are now marked 2. Then I will create a second cronjob to reset all records (2.3) back to 1? Does this make sense?

Comment: @JaySmoke No. *Create stored procedure **which performs all described steps** and selects marked records.*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you made a cron that hits a URL something like

```
http://yourdomain.com/fetch-rows
```

or a script for instance, like

```
your_project_folder/fetch-rows.php
```

Let's say you have a DB table in place that looks something like this:

```
| id | offset | created_at          |
|----|--------|---------------------|
| 1  | 100    | 2019-01-08 03:15:00 |
| 2  | 200    | 2019-01-08 04:15:00 |
```

**Your script:**

```
<?php

define('FETCH_LIMIT',100);

$conn = mysqli_connect(....); // connect to DB

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cron_hit_table where id = (select max(id) from cron_hit_table)")); // select the last record to get the latest offset

$offset = 0; // initial default offset

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $offset = intval(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['offset']);
}


// Now, hit your query with $offset included

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset,100");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // your data processing
}

// insert new row to store next offset for next cron hit

$offset += FETCH_LIMIT; // increment current offset

mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cron_hit_table(offset) values($offset)"); // because ID would be auto increment and created_at would have default value as current_timestamp


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Whenever cron hits, you fetch last row from your hit table to get the offset. Hit the query with that offset and store the next offset for next hit in your table.

**Update:**

As pointed out by **@Dharman** in the comments, you can use **[PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** for more abstracted way of dealing with different types of database(but make sure you have appropriate driver for it, see [checklist of drivers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) PDO supports to be sure) along with minor checks of query syntaxes.

Comment: This solution goes beyond my knowledge hence why I couldn't understand it or use it.

Comment: I would not recommend MySQLi.

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to use properly and there's better alternative: PDO. Even your example shows that you are not sure how to use mysqli properly. Using it without any abstraction layer will just cause you headaches. If you are starting a new project use a proper DB abstraction library or use PDO.

Comment: @Dharman Updated my answer. Also, what do you mean by  _Even your example shows that you are not sure how to use mysqli properly_  ?

Comment: Your example contains few cargo cult elements. You don't use OOP style. You never enabled mysqli error reporting. You use while loop to fetch the records. You close the connection at the end of the script. None of this things are wrong, but they are very poor practices. If we want to teach others how to code properly we should avoid spreading them.

Comment: @Dharman Well this wasn't technically written to be directly added to production code. Apparently, OP found even this high level(maybe a newbie). Yes, I do agree that error reporting wasn't enabled and I didn't use OOP style, but why us using while loop to fetch records an issue?

Comment: Why would you ever need to use while loop? Why not use `foreach` or simply `fetch_all` into an array? This practices of using `while` loop is confusing and often causes more problems. It doesn't solve any real problems and people just blindly copy it over thinking there is no better way.

Comment: @Dharman I think this is kind of opinion based. Sure, `fetch_all()` and `foreach` is a good alternative but using a while loop doesn't seem confusing to me. If someone deals with internal seek pointer inside a while loop, they will have to take care of it as it is their (developer's) responsibility, in which case fetch_all() would serve better.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Akina and @Vivek_23 for your contributions. I was able to figure out an easier way to go about it.

1. Add a new field to table, eg *shownstatus*
2. Create a cronjob to display 100 (LIMIT 100) records with their *shownstatus* not marked as **shown** from table every hour and then update each record's *shownstatus* to **shown** NB. If I create a cronjob to run every hour for the whole day, I can get all records displayed and their *shownstatus* updated to **shown** by close of day.
3. Create a second cronjob to update all record's *shownstatus* to notshown

*The downside to this is that, you can only display a total of 2,400 records a day. ie. 100 records every hour times 24hrs. So if your record grows to about 10,000. You will need to set your cronjob to run for atleast 5 days to display all records.*

Still open to a better approach if there's any, but till then, I will have to just stick to this for now.

Comment: You wrote _Create a second cronjob to update all record's shownstatus to notshown and you can repeat the process over and over._ Why would you do that? Doing this way, you always only show 2 same batches of records.

Comment: If my answer was applicable and made sense for your use case, I see no reason to have extra column for marked/non marked rows. It is space consuming which Akina didn't reply to.

Comment: @vivek_23 the whole process should be repeatable. I forgot to add that. Sorry. That's why you have to mark the statusshown as notshown so that you can repeat the whole process again when you want ie weekly.

Comment: Why will you want to show the same set of rows twice on the screen?